# Set RedirectUrl in JsonResult Action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to implement demo application to learn ASP.NET MVC. Application have three views and corresponding actions and also have login feature.

**Views:**

1. Index.cshtml - contains person information grid
2. PersonInfoView.cshtml - display person information in view mode
3. PersonInfoEdit.cshtml - allow user to edit person information

**Default Route:**

```
  routes.MapRouteWithName(
            "Default", // Route name
            "", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Person", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

**For Person view and Edit I created following routes:**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
          "ViewPerson", // Route name
          "View/{PersonId}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "Person", action = "PersonInfoView", PersonId= "" } // Parameter defaults
      );



 routes.MapRoute(
           "EditPerson", // Route name
           "{PersonId}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Person", action = "PersonInfoEdit", PersonId= "" } // Parameter defaults
       );
```

So, url for edit person will be "localhost/1" & for view "localhost/view/1"

User can view or edit person information. The option edit(in Index) available in case user status is logged in. I have login button (which open Jquery Dialog) in PersonInfoView.cshtml (if user is not logged) which allows user to login in application.

I want to redirect user to edit page if user logins to application via PersonInfoView.cshtml page.

**Login user action returns JsonResult:**

```
return Json(new { res = 1, RedirectUrl = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

How can I set RedirectUrl equals to person edit view if user login to application via PersonInfoView.cshtml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common scenario is to redirect to PersonInfoEdit, but mark it with `[Authorize]` attribute.

In case user is logged in, he'll get editing page, otherwise he'll be redirected to authorization page. After successful authorization he'll be finally redirected to editing page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but in my application what i want is that if user is not logged in then user will always get "localhost/view/1". if user is logged in then it's possible from index page that user can choose view or edit option. In case not logged in then I want to display login button in PersonInfoView to login in application. here login not redirect to any page but displayed as popup(user name and password). and on login successfully, I want to redirect user to edit page if user login to application via PersonInfoView.cshtml page

Comment: If you login with ajax, you'll need a client-side JavaScript, like `if (success) window.location = "@Url.Action("PersonInfoEdit", "Person")";`

Comment: is it possible to post to POST method for example in above PersonInfoEdit could be post method

Answer (score 0):

You can use Url.Action

```
public ActionResult PersonInfoView()
{
   var personId = 1;
   var redirectionUrl = Url.Action("PersonInfoEdit", "Person", new { PersonId = personId });
   return Json(new { res = 1, RedirectUrl = redirectionUrl }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

javascript for client side redirect

```
$(function(){
   $("#login").click(function(){
       $.post('@Url.Action("PersonInfoView","Person")',function(data){
           if(data.res == 1)
           {
               location.href = data.RedirectUrl;
           }
       });
       return false;
   });
})
```